# Passing props to a component through state

Tags: javascript, react-native

**Prefix:**

I am working with react-native, and am wondering the best practice for passing props down from a parent to a child component.  I have tested this on my android device only.

**Question:**

From my understanding it is possible to pass values to a component through the use of props, ie:

```
<myComponent myProp="some data" />
```

and it can be referenced in my myComponent using `this.props.myProp`. Would it be bad practice (or will it even work) to create my state object in the constructor like so:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    myStateProp: this.props.myProp
  };
}
```

which could then be called in that component as `this.state.myStateProp`.  I am relatively new to react-native and am trying to learn as much as I can.  I have tried it in several use cases with varying results, and am uncertain as to the behavior.  Thank you for your input!

Comment: Sure, you can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few good reasons to do this. It's generally considered an anti-pattern because components should be stateless wherever possible.

If what you're trying to do is control the component by passing in props and using as state, I would suggest holding the state in the parent component and then passing any changes back up the chain via props, using a callback.

For example

```
ComponentOne {
    this.state = { colour:red }

    handleColourChange(val){
        this.setState({ colour: val })
    }

    return <ComponentTwo changeColour={this.handleColourChange} colour={this.state.colour} />
}
```

Then imagine in ComponentTwo we have a button and you want to change colour:

```
<button onClick={this.changeColour(blue)}>Change to blue</button>
```

This way your child component remains stateless, and is controlled by its parent. `this.props.colour` will change in the child automatically.